# how do i calculate the total billed amount for a particular day?

Tags: sql

I have a database table where there is a field- billed_amount which keeps the records of the billed amount for a particular person and another field- billing_date. Now,I want to display the total billed amount for all people for a particular day, for example today, to generate day to day sales report.

Comment: The database I'm using is SQL server management studio 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

For a particular day you could run the following, changing the date to whatever date you're running it for.

```
select sum(billed_amount)
from tbl
where billing_date = '2014-07-19'
```

Note that each database varies with its default date format. (you didn't specify a database)

To get the total for each date ("grouped by" date), you can use the following:

```
select billing_date, sum(billed_amount)
from tbl
group by billing_date
order by billing_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by` day, and `sum` the amounts billed:

```
select  cast(billing_date as date)
,       sum(billing_amount)
from    YourTable
group by
        cast(billing_date as date)
```

Date operations vary by database.  In SQL Server 2008+, you can cast a `datetime` to the `date` type to strip off the time.